# Cannot insert Data from CSV into SQL table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code to import data from a CSV file to a sql table. When I run the code no error are displayed. However nothing is inserted into the SQL table.

```vb
    Dim folder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Data\"
    Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [labanal2.csv]", CnStr)

        Adp.Fill(dt)
    End Using


    Dim strsql As String = "insert into ontledings (PLAASNO,PLAASNAAM,BLOKNO,AREA,NAME3,KULTIVAR,WINGKLAS,ANALISEDATUM,SUIKER,pH,SUUR) values (@PLAASNO,@PLAASNAAM,@BLOKNO,@AREA,@NAME3,@KULTIVAR,@WINGKLAS,@ANALISEDATUM,@SUIKER,@pH,@SUUR)"

    Dim SqlconnectionString As String = "Data Source=GIDEON-E-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=SkeduleringDatabasis;Integrated Security=True"

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strsql, connection)

        With cmd.Parameters



            .Add("@PLAASNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "PLAASNO")
            .Add("@PLAASNAAM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "PLAASNAAM")
            .Add("@BLOKNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "BLOKNO")
            .Add("@AREA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "AREA")
            .Add("@ANALISEDATUM", SqlDbType.Date, 50, "ANALISEDATUM")
            .Add("@NAME3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "NAME3")
            .Add("@KULTIVAR", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "KULTIVAR")
            .Add("@WINGKLAS", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "WINGKLAS")
            .Add("@SUIKER", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "SUIKER")
            .Add("@pH", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "pH")
            .Add("@SUUR", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "SUUR")


        End With

        Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.InsertCommand = cmd
        Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = adapter.Update(dt)

        MsgBox("Klaar OLEB")
    End Using
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What database are you using? "SQL" is just the query language - not a database product ....

Comment: use executenonquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that each row in your DataTable has the RowState = DataRowState.Unchanged. This means that each row is simply ignored when you call Update.

This is the normal behavior expected by the Update method, only the rows in state Added, Changed or Deleted are taken in consideration for the Insert, Update or Delete command.

You can add this loop before calling update

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    row.SetAdded()
Next
```

Or, as explained below by Plutonix, change the behavior of the Fill method setting the property `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to False

```vb
Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [labanal2.csv]", CnStr)
    Adp.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
    Adp.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

This will leave the RowState property with the DataRowState.Added flag active.

Comment: You can tell the DataAdapter not to AcceptChanges when loading.  Before loading the DataTable:   `myDA.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False`

Comment: Thank you Steve and Plutonix.